# Is there an iPhone URL shortcut for calendar?

Tags: iphone, calendar, shortcut

I can launch Google Maps, Mail, Safari and others... but is there the same functionality for Calendar??

EDIT: I only want to add an event into the calendar.

Thanks guys!

Nick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calendar application is not listed as an application that can be launched using a URL in the [Apple URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html).

The following applications are listed as supported:

- Mail
- Phone
- SMS
- Maps
- YouTube
- iTunes

Comment: I think you might be correct here... unless anyone knows of a backdoor to add an entry to the calendar through hook or crook? N

Comment: @JasperPol The answer is still largely correct (FaceTime should be added), but there are *unsupported, undocumented* schemes - such as `calshow://` that also work - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658685/how-to-open-native-ios-app-calendar-notes-from-a-link-on-website?lq=1); though it's unclear to me whether you can do more with them than simply *launch* the app in question.

Answer (score 15):

That code launch the Calendar app:

```
NSString* launchUrl = @"calshow://";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: launchUrl]];
```

Comment: Undocumented, but still works as of iOS 7; can you do more than simply *launch* the Calendar app with it, though? Can you create an entry or jump to a specific date?

Comment: Is this legal way to call calendar? As you told its undocumented method to call. will apple reject while app submission???? @mklement0

Comment: @Ramdy: Good question - I do not know, but it seems that rejection is a possibility; see http://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/10/15/apple-undocumented-apis/

Comment: @mklement0, look on this statement "As a result, this document does not describe all URL schemes supported on different Apple platforms." from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH1-SW1 . Is this statement means, still there are many legal url  schemes available in iOS platform?

Comment: Any idea what the format is for launching a specific date? Like `calshow://<timestamp>` or something...

Comment: calshow:{seconds since 1 Jan 2001 00:00}, e.g. launchUrl = @"calshow:50000"; (without slashes)

Answer (score 2):

Answering the EDIT part of your answer: You can add/delete event from calendar programmatically. See SO question: [Deleting an event from iPhone's calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665014/deleting-an-event-from-iphones-calendar/7360365#7360365)

Answer (score 1):

All those things you mentioned can be easily used to launch the application and go some where:

- Google Maps: go to an address
- Mail: open a message to send to an e-mail address
- Safari: go to a web address

But with the calendar the only real thing you can do is add an event.  If this is what you want to do, I think you can just do either of these two suggestions:

start your URL with ical://www.somesite.com/event-information.ical
Or drop the special scheme and just do http://www.somesite.com/even-information.ical

But there is no way that I am aware of where you can just jump to a certain date in the calendar.

Comment: Hi there - this is exactly what I want to do, but neither of your suggestions worked.

using 'ical://www.somesite.com/event-information.ical', the iPhone refuses to open the URL, and 'http://www.somesite.com/even-information.ical' I get the message 'Cannot Subscribe - Could not subscribe to the calendar entry'! 

Thanks loads for your suggestions though, this is on the right track!

Nick.

Answer (score 1):

With iOS 4.0 you now have access to the new Calendar API.

Comment: Apple calls it the Event Kit framework - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/datamanagement/conceptual/eventkitprogguide/Introduction/Introduction.html - but note that while it offers _programmatic manipulation_ of calendar events and even reminders, you cannot _launch/activate_ the Calendar _app_.

Answer (score 0):

as state above. calshow:// but you can use calshow:

it works if you omit the // and replace with the date in time interval (guessing since 1970 or 2001)

[URL scheme for opening native calendar with specific event id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135477/url-scheme-for-opening-native-calendar-with-specific-event-id)