# Does iOS Calendar support a URL scheme?

Tags: ios, push

Is there any URL scheme that will launch the Calendar app on iOS?

I use Prowl to push Growl notifications to my phone. They just added support to launch an app with a URL based on the notification. I tried cal:// caldav:// and ical:// without any luck.

Answer (score 8):

Try this. it works for me. Here is the [link](http://ijustwannashare.blogspot.com/2013/12/url-scheme-for-ios-7.html)

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"calshow://"]];
```

Comment: how to pass event's data so that when Calendar app open, it should open Add Event scree with pre filled data?

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** you can now use the `calshow://` URL to open the Calendar app on iOS.

---

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341627/is-there-an-iphone-url-shortcut-for-calendar): Apple does not list this application on its [Apple URL Scheme Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html).