# Embedded Webkit and calendar attachment

Tags: ios, facebook, webkit

I'm dealing with a web application that allows reminders to be set by linking to an endpoint that generates a .VCS file.  Most browsers, including Safari on iPhones and iPads, open the file in the calendar app, allowing a reminder to be set.

This works well in all circumstances except Facebook. Recently the Facebook application on iOS started using an embedded Webkit browser to open links instead of launching Safari.

Unlike Safari, the embedded Webkit attempts to render the .VCS file instead of opening the calendar app, displaying a "Cannot Render" error messages. I cannot seem to coerce embedded webkit into downloading the calendar file and opening the calendar. I have tried:

- Renaming the file to .ics instead of vcs
- using a "webcal://" url instead of http://
- setting the content-type to "text/calendar"

Is there anything else I can try? How does embedded Webkit decide what to do with an attachment?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does iOS Calendar support a URL scheme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820762/does-ios-calendar-support-a-url-scheme)