# How to pass NSString data from my app to iOS native app Notes

Tags: ios

evening everyone, I'm working on one feature of my app, basically what it does is when user typed some text in the textfield in my app, then hit the send button, those typed-in text would be sent to the iOS native Notes app, create a new note and display those text in the new note. I don't have a clue how to implement this after did some searching in the official document (I looked into the About Apple URL Schemes, but didn't find Notes listed one of the available app to send to), any hint would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open native iOS app (calendar, notes...) from a link on website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658685/how-to-open-native-ios-app-calendar-notes-from-a-link-on-website)

Comment: Thank you Sha, followed the link you posted, didn't find the answer I'm looking for, but there's some valuable information I can definitely use on my app, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are official, documented APIs for creating entries in Reminders, Calendar and Contacts, Apple does not currently offer an API for creating Notes. This is as of iOS SDK 7.1, but maybe it will change in the future.

Comment: thank you melsam! good to know, I'll figure something else out then.