# ios: how to email a link to users that will open a mobile app rather than a web page?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Apologies in advance for a very dumb question, but I am not finding a good search string for google or SO.

I notice that some mobile apps send me emails and when I click on those links, I go directly to their app on my phone rather than to a web page. How is this done/what is the name of this mechanism?

Thank you for any info.

Answer (score 1):

These are called URL schemes, or a URL hook. Check out this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7658785/544094

Comment: @thank you Chris and others. apologies for duplicating a question.